# How can we get all images present in device with name and show a grid view?

Tags: android

I want to get All Images present in device show in `GridView` With Real Path And Thumbnails image. My problem is that "I am Get all image present in device but not get real path of image". My code is give below. I want name of image below not Thumbnails path.

```
   **button.java**


    public class button extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i1= new Intent(button.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });
    }
**MainActivity.java**

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    /**
     * Grid view holding the images.
     */
    private GridView sdcardImages;
    /**
     * Image adapter for the grid view.
     */
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    /**
     * Display used for getting the width of the screen.
     */
    private Display display;

    public Object data = null;

    /**
     * Creates the content view, sets up the grid, the adapter, and the click
     * listener.
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Request progress bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.sdcard);

        display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();

        setupViews();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        loadImages();
    }

    /**
     * Free up bitmap related resources.
     */
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
        final int count = grid.getChildCount();
        ImageView v = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
            ((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).setCallback(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setup the grid view.
     */
    private void setupViews() {
        sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setNumColumns(display.getWidth() / 95);
        sdcardImages.setClipToPadding(false);
        sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Load images.
     */
    private void loadImages() {
        data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (data == null) {
            new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
        } else {
            final LoadedImage[] photos = (LoadedImage[]) data;
            if (photos.length == 0) {
                new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
            }
            for (LoadedImage photo : photos) {
                addImage(photo);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add image(s) to the grid view adapter.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            Array of LoadedImages references
     */
    private void addImage(LoadedImage... value) {
        for (LoadedImage image : value) {
            imageAdapter.addPhoto(image);
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save bitmap images into a list and return that list.
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
     */
    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
        final int count = grid.getChildCount();
        final LoadedImage[] list = new LoadedImage[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final ImageView v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);

            list[i] = new LoadedImage(
                    ((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), null, null);
        }

        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Async task for loading the images from the SD card.
     * 
     * @author Mihai Fonoage
     *
     */

    class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<Object, LoadedImage, Object> {

        /**
         * Load images from SD Card in the background, and display each image on
         * the screen.
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Bitmap newBitmap = null;
            Uri uri = null;

            // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null, // Return all rows
                    null, null);
            int columnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            int image_column_index_next = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            int size = cursor.getCount();
            // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
            if (size == 0) {
                // No Images available, post some message to the user
            }
            int imageID = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                                + imageID);
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(uri));
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100,
                                true);
                        bitmap.recycle();
                        if (newBitmap != null) {
                            String filename = cursor
                                    .getString(image_column_index_next);
                            File f = new File(filename);
                            publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap,
                                    f.getName(), f.getName()));

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Error fetching image, try to recover
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Add a new LoadedImage in the images grid.
         *
         * @param value
         *            The image.
         */
        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... value) {
            addImage(value);
        }

        /**
         * Set the visibility of the progress bar to false.
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     * 
     * @author Mihai Fonoage
     *
     */
    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<LoadedImage> photos = new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();
        public LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addPhoto(LoadedImage photo) {
            photos.add(photo);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return photos.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return photos.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_click2,
                        null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.textview = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbText);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            LoadedImage item = photos.get(position);
            holder.textview.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(item.mBitmap);
            holder.textview.setText(item.mName);
            ;
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A LoadedImage contains the Bitmap loaded for the image.
     */
    private static class LoadedImage {
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        String mName;
        String mPath;

        LoadedImage(Bitmap bitmap, String Name, String Path) {
            mBitmap = bitmap;
            mName = Name;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return mBitmap;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        public String getPAth() {
            return mPath;
        }
    }

    /**
     * When an image is clicked, load that image as a puzzle.
     */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            columnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            FileInputStream is = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                        parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                // Display bitmap (useThisBitmap)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Try to recover
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    projection = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
**ViewHolder.java**

    class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    TextView textview;
}

**activity_main.xml**

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

**image_click2.xml**

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thumbText"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="This is an image"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

</LinearLayout>

**sdcard.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/sdcard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```